# How to speed up Nexus 4 emulator in android studio 2.2 on windows 7?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-emulator

I am suffering long time with slow builds and slow emulator.

I installed haxm, enabled vt in bios, enabled offline work and run in parallel options. I also set Graphics to be emulated on hardware.

But alas gradle build of simple project takes 1 - 2 minutes and starting emulator is really slow. When emulator is running google chrome hangs often.

My system settings are

[image]

I also moved cache android studio folder and cache emulator folder and ide and emulator away from User directory. My user directory is now only 439 mb.

How to speed up it all?

Thank you!

Comment: Install more RAM. Install an SSD.

Comment: One of solutions is use Genymotion, it is much faster

Comment: I normally run my Android Studio and store my SDK in an external HDD or internal SSD. It takes the pressure off your own device regarding the RAM usage. Or upgrade your own RAM.

Comment: make sure the emulator is using x64 or x86 image - not arm/arm64.  also enable the host gpu option